# How to solve issue related to iterating over list in Python3 refactoring

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I ran 2to3 module, but this issue was not auto fixed when I moved my scripts from Python2 to 3...can anyone help me with this?

classes_to_text is a list containing entries such as "200 Photos" and "125 Videos", and the following is throwing an error:

```
classes_to_text1[i] = int([x for x in classes_to_text[i] if x.isdigit()])

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: This code works on *neither* Python3 nor Python2.

Comment: weird...that means that 2to3 changed it to something that does not work

Comment: What was the original code?

Comment: classes_to_text1[i] = int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), classes_to_text[i]))

Comment: According to the docs, [Python2 ``filter`` is special-cased for ``str`` and ``tuple``.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter) For these types, ``filter`` preserves the type instead of returning a ``list`` as for all other types.

Comment: 2to3 is useful, but it's not very "smart". Some things you have to fix manually. A very common case is where you used a plain `str` in Python 2 but you need a `bytes` string in Python 3

Comment: Yup. I've fixed several of those issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* feeding a list into `int(..)` so the error message is correct.

Fix it by joining that list into a single string again:

```
classes_to_text1[i] = int(''.join([x for x in classes_to_text[i] if x.isdigit()]))
```

Comment: awesome TY! looks like an issue with 2to3 module...since it changed it to something that works in neither 2 or 3...but your solutions works.

Comment: @cjg123: just out of curiosity, can you trace back what the original line was in P2.7? If so it might be useful to add to your question.

Comment: classes_to_text1[i] = int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), classes_to_text[i])). -- thanks again!

Comment: @cjg123: funny enough, there is nothing wrong with that line *except* for the very same issue: `outp = int(''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), inp)))`